# Unable to retrieve persisted data with spring data redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am new to redis but understand the fundamentals. I am trying to add users to a list that have *joined* a chatroom. I am using the RedisTemplate from spring data redis.

Added is done via: `redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush("voting", user.getName());`

On the redis server using `KEYS *` returns: `2) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06voting"`

However using: `GET` and I keep seeing nil using:

- \xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06voting
- voting

as keys.

I'm not sure what the prefix of `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06` is? Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My own stupidity. The key was an `org.bson.ObjectId` not a `java.lang.String`

using the `MONITOR` on the redis was able to help me see the error